# JOIN two table to themselves and calculate a value based on the two

Tags: sql, join, self-join

Using SQL Server 2012

I have two tables that are joined.

```
[APXFirm].[AdvApp].[vMarketIndexRate]

[APXFirm].[AdvApp].[vMarketIndex]
```

Joining just these two I am able to get IndexName, AsofDate and Rate

However I want to calculate the weighted sum of two indexes. S&P500 weighted by .4 and DJ Average weighted by .6. I tried the query below and get a result but it is not the blended rate. It is the first indexes rate.

For example if on a given date SP = 100 and DJ = 200 the blend rate should be
40 + 120 = 160

Here is my query

```
USE APXFIRM
SELECT 'Blend' AS 'IndexName', ir1.AsOfDate,

  SUM(ir1.rate*.4+ir2.rate*.6) AS 'blendrate'
  FROM [APXFirm].[AdvApp].[vMarketIndexRate] IR1
   INNER JOIN [APXFirm].[AdvApp].[vMarketIndex] MI1
    ON IR1.indexid = mi1.indexid 
    INNER JOIN [APXFirm].[AdvApp].[vMarketIndexRate] IR2
    ON ir2.indexid = ir1.indexid AND ir2.asofdate = ir1.asofdate
    INNER JOIN [APXFirm].[AdvApp].[vMarketIndex] MI2
    ON ir2.indexid = ir1.indexid AND ir2.asofdate = ir1.asofdate
  WHERE mi1.indexname = 'sp'
  AND  mi2.indexname = 'djind'
  GROUP BY MI1.IndexName ,
           IR1.AsOfDate ,
           IR1.Rate ,
           MI2.IndexName ,
           IR2.AsOfDate ,
           IR2.Rate
```

Here is a sample of all data. Note that weight is not an actual column. I just included it for illustrative purposes.

```
IndexName   AsOfDate    rate    weight  IndexName   AsOfDate    rate    weight  BlendRate
SP500   12/31/2012      100        0.6  DowJones    12/31/2012  90      0.4     96
SP500   1/31/2013       110        0.6  DowJones    1/31/2013   95      0.4     104
SP500   2/28/2013       120        0.6  DowJones    2/28/2013   100     0.4     112
SP500   3/31/2013       130        0.6  DowJones    3/31/2013   110     0.4     122
```

Here is the desired output.

```
IndexName   AsOfDate    BlendRate
Blend   12/31/2012      96
Blend   1/31/2013       104
Blend   2/28/2013       112
Blend   3/31/2013       122
```

Comment: Can you add sample data and expected output

Comment: what's the output you are currently getting?

Comment: Did you try left join instead of inner join?

Comment: I did try a left join. I think in general I have joined the tables wrong. LEFT JOIN may work if the overall query is ammended.

Comment: If i understood your problem right, I think you didn't need group by, You can just multiply and add values to get the weighted sum, try removing sum and group by

Comment: can you share your tables schema(columns in each table)?

Comment: Shouldn't the join condition after `INNER JOIN [APXFirm].[AdvApp].[vMarketIndex] MI2` be `ON IR2.indexid = mi2.indexid`? Does the query work when this correction is made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you problem right, the problem is in "from" block - try to use the next one:

```
SELECT 'Blend' AS 'IndexName'
      ,ir1.AsOfDate
      ,SUM(ir1.rate*.4+ir2.rate*.6) AS 'blendrate'

FROM [APXFirm].[AdvApp].[vMarketIndexRate] IR1
     INNER JOIN [APXFirm].[AdvApp].[vMarketIndex] MI1
             ON IR1.indexid = mi1.indexid 
     INNER JOIN [APXFirm].[AdvApp].[vMarketIndexRate] IR2
             ON ir2.asofdate = ir1.asofdate
     INNER JOIN [APXFirm].[AdvApp].[vMarketIndex] MI2
             ON ir2.indexid = mi2.indexid

WHERE mi1.indexname = 'sp'
  AND mi2.indexname = 'djind'

GROUP BY MI1.IndexName
        ,IR1.AsOfDate
        ,IR1.Rate
        ,MI2.IndexName
        ,IR2.AsOfDate
        ,IR2.Rate
```

Answer (score 0):

Your group by is incorrect:

```
SELECT
    'Blend' AS 'IndexName',
    ir1.AsOfDate,
    SUM(ir1.rate*.4+ir2.rate*.6) AS 'blendrate'
FROM ...
...
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

If you group by more columns than selected, yo'll get multiple rows for each of your intended groups (one for each combination of the columns listed in the group by.